# Http connect request from multiple IP address to destination in python

Tags: python, http, connect

conn=httlib.HTTPConnection(self.proxy)

Self.proxy has destination ip and port.

I want to do multiple connection from multiple IP addresses to destination
How to specify the source IP while connect request.Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I want the different connections to show different source ip addresses?

Comment: I have configured 10 virtual ip (like 198.168.1.1 to 198.168.1.10) in same machine. here, i want to use multiple IP to destination while doing connect request? you got me?

Comment: ah, yes. I get you now.  You should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have multiple network connections on the same computer (i.e. a wired and wireless connection) and you want to make sure that your connect goes over a specific interface.

In general you cannot do this. How your traffic is sent to a specific ip address, and therefore what source ip address it shows, is determined by your operating system's routing tables. As you haven't specified what operating system this I can't go into more detail.

You may be able to do this using some of the more advanced routing configuration, but that's an operating system level problem and can't be done through Python.

Comment: @saranhary If you have multiple NICs you could simply call the shell command `route add -host [destination IP] gw [gateway IP] metric 0 dev [interface name]` before your do your HTTP connection, then call `route del -host [destination IP] gw [gateway IP] dev [interface name]` afterwards, but if you have 1 NIC with multiple IP's this is probably not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution but not 100%
Requirement: Has to send request from 10 Ip address to one destination. 
Achieved the same through the following API
class httplib.HTTPConnection(host[, port[, strict[, timeout[, source_address]]]])

here, we can mention the last parameter source IP
Like, httlib.HTTPConnection(dest_ip, dest_port, src_ip)
 For Example:httlib.HTTPConnection("198.168.1.5",8080,"198.168.1.1")
created the connection under for loop for 10 unique src ip addresses.

Output: Connected to destination with 10 different port number with same IP address. I don't know why it happens like this.
Problem solved. Thanks for all.